# mongoexport - query fails

Tags: mongoexport

I'm facing an issue which seems actually not to be new, but depsite my searches, I'm stucked.
I run mongoExport on a windows terminal, and want to add a simple query to my export.

- If I write : --query='{"type":"PersonNatural"}',  I got : invalid character 'P' looking for beginning of value

Then I read that it might be a question of single vs double quotes.

- So I wrote : --query="{'type':'PersonNatural'}", but received : Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input

I tried to read about Extended Json, tried a lot of different combinations (single quotes, double ones, spaces, curly braces, back slash...), but doesn't work.
I guess the answer must be simple, but can't see it.

Thanks for your help !

=> I finally found a solution :

--query='{\ "type\ ":\ "PersonNatural\ "}' (pls remove all spaces)

seems it just needed to escape the : "

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.